# Correspondence table with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, mapping, series

Recently, I used pandas to manipulate a csv with electoral data. In my DataFrame, I've got a column 'winner' for each city of an area.

It could be represented as :

```
       city         winner
0      city1        party1
1      city2        party3
2      city3        party1
3      city4        party2
4      city5        party1
...
5188   city5189     party3
```

Here's the thing: I want to create a new column, named "coulour". The goal is to have an unique colour per city, depending on 'winner' value.

To do that I could use if/elif statements, but I was wondering if it's posible to use a correspondence table. For example, if I've got my huge DataFrame on one hand, and this little one on the other :

```
       winner       colour
0      party1       #000
1      party2       #fff
2      party3       #c0c0c0
```

Could I use one fonction of pandas to match display the good value of 'colour' if values of 'winner' are matching in the two DataFrames ?

I've tried map() function and get_loc(), but it didn't work very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created from `df2`:

```
print (df2.set_index('winner')['colour'])
winner
party1       #000
party2       #fff
party3    #c0c0c0
Name: colour, dtype: object

df1['new'] = df1.winner.map(df2.set_index('winner')['colour'])
print (df1)
          city  winner      new
0        city1  party1     #000
1        city2  party3  #c0c0c0
2        city3  party1     #000
3        city4  party2     #fff
4        city5  party1     #000
5188  city5189  party3  #c0c0c0
```

Another solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) (`on='winner'` can be omit if only common column in both `DataFrame` is `winner`):

```
print (pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left'))
       city  winner   colour
0     city1  party1     #000
1     city2  party3  #c0c0c0
2     city3  party1     #000
3     city4  party2     #fff
4     city5  party1     #000
5  city5189  party3  #c0c0c0
```